# What are the identities of these Chinese folk symbols?

Tags: character-identification

I need help identifying the symbols of this image ([source](https://lens.google.com/search?p=AcLkwR26ZW8NrT_D4SIpUKa_tM5_oIDc38a71Ca1to7nRenwiSchhQbfage7Da16mdSNRgPt8BOScR1erLefmqVzrnFuAM9MDW2sCcFYlSD82EH15CFXqV17AWouCx2pJJB4yqE04bZQO5fggR1e5rfv0Olz3seodwEVhM_0Sjeaq5dy-2zhRijOpETeFovLz2IMAA9MyLBtXrh85k0z10xK88iYxL9McHS1qh5HGklZk7rwT6O6EEEinA%3D%3D&ep=gisbubu&hl=en&re=df#lns=W251bGwsbnVsbCxudWxsLG51bGwsbnVsbCxudWxsLG51bGwsIkVrY0tKR0l6TkdNeU5tVTFMVGs1TTJZdE5ESTVZaTA1WkdZNUxUVm1OalpqTlRReE9ERXlOQklmV1ROM1pUaFJYMGhVWDNkVlJVWkRjWGQ0VEhKTVVEVnhlVloxVjFKNFp3PT0iXQ==)):

> [image: nine circular symbols in black and white, some of which may represent Chinese characters]

Google claims these are "traditional oriental Korean symmetrical zen symbols in black symbolizing longevity," but I would like a description of each symbol.

Comment: there’re nine symbols in each groups, which one do you want to know?

Answer (score 1):

Known to me:

[image]

**陰陽** - Yin and yang, a Chinese philosophical concept that describes opposite but interconnected forces. The symbol is a diagram of taijitu (太極圖). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yin_and_yang
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taijitu

[image]

**福** - felicity, luck, good fortune.

[image]

**祿** - wealth and prosperity.

[image] [[image][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCYLI.png)

**壽** - life (length), also longevity.